# Convert Json Date with 12 digits Python Datetime

Tags: json, python-3.x, date, datetime

I am receiving a `json` which I convert to `DataFrame df`. One of the column is with Dates this format 
 `/Date(950842800000)/`,  `/Date(1000436400000)/`, ...

The problem is that One of this dates has 12 digit and the others 13 digits. This one with 13 digits are converted fine, and with 12 there is a problem. The way I am converting

```
df["Data"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[6:-2][:10])) if len(x) > 12 else datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[6:-2][:11])))
```

doesn´t work for 12 digits.
Thank You for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short:**

```
lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[6:-2][:-3]))
```

**Long:**

If you have such input data:

```
"/Date(950842800000)/",
"/Date(1000436400000)/"
```

Than a few modifications will make script working correctly:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [
    "/Date(950842800000)/",
    "/Date(1000436400000)/"
]


for d in dates:
    l = lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[6:-2][:9])) if len(x) < 21 else datetime.fromtimestamp(
                int(x[6:-2][:10]))
    print(l(d))
```

produce:

```
2000-02-18 04:00:00
2001-09-14 05:00:00
```

what is what you expect.

But then we may think to simplicity, you may just use:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [
    "/Date(950842800000)/",
    "/Date(1000436400000)/"
]


for d in dates:
    l = lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[6:-2][:-3]))
    print(l(d))
```

Comment: The longer answer works, the shorter doesn't EDIT: short also works, sorry and thanks