# python json date object to python datetime

Tags: python, date

I have a JSON object with a date that returns

```
print row['ApplicationReceivedDateTime']

/Date(1454475600000)/
```

how do I process this using the pythons datetime module?

```
print type(row['ApplicationReceivedDateTime'])
```

returns `<type 'unicode'>`

`print repr(row['ApplicationReceivedDateTime'])`

returns `u'/Date(1454475600000)/'`

Comment: What would be the output, is that as string?

Comment: What format is the date number in?

Comment: Where are the slashes coming from?  Show us the output of `print repr(row['ApplicationReceivedDateTime'])`.

Comment: @JohnGordon that is what prints out

Comment: first answer pretty much explains it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092831/convert-json-date-with-12-digits-python-datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like milliseconds. Try dividing by 1000.

```
import datetime as dt

>>> dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(1454475600000 / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 2, 21, 0)
```

If the date is in the string format per your question, extract the numeric portion using `re`.

```
date = '/Date(1454475600000)/'
>>> dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(re.findall(r"\d+", date)[0]) / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 2, 21, 0)
```

Comment: I was going to post it using: `epoch = int(re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", a))/1000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` to get the integer value  and then use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` to get the date value:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

string_time = row['ApplicationReceivedDateTime']
parsed_time = int(re.search('\((\d+)\)', string_time)[1]) / 1e3 #1e3 == 1000
rcvd_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(parsed_time)

print(rcvd_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Prints:

```
'2016-02-03 05:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

And the values of Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second and F, for that you can write a manual function for that like this

```
def generate_date_time_str(date_str):
"""Login to parse the date str"""
return date_str
```

the date_str will look link this

> "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"

There is no python module directly convert any random date str to DateTime object